# @Context injection in Stateless EJB used by JAX-RS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jax-rs

I have something like this setup below. This is a simplified version but I think it gets the basic idea across. I am using Jersey 2.16, Java 1.8, and Glassfish Open Source 4.1

```
public interface IReportService {
    String addNewReport(Report report);
}

@Path("reports")
public class ReportResource implements IReportService {
    /**
    * Service layer.
    */
    @EJB
    private transient ReportService service;

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Override
    public String addNewReport(final Report report) {
       return service.addNewReport(report);
    }
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ReportService implements IReportService {

   @EJB
   private IReportPersistence reportPersistence;

   @Context
   SecurityContext secContext;

   public String addNewReport(final Report report) {
       report.setUserName(secContext.getUserPrincipal().getName());
       reportPersistence.persist(report);
    }
}
```

But when I deploy and try to hit the web-service I get a NullPointer exception from the security context. It just seems that the Context is not being injected at all. I checked and it's the secContext variable itself, not just the return from getUserPrincipal() that is null. There are no warning or exceptions in the Glassfish log besides my NullPointer (which results in a 500 error returned to the web client).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `SecurityContext` in the wrong place. You have to use it inside your REST resource class.

You can try the following:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Override
public String addNewReport(final Report report, @Context SecurityContext sc) {
   report.setUserName(sC.getUserPrincipal().getName());
   return service.addNewReport(report);
}
```

For more details have a look at the [Jersey Documentation - Chapter 16. Security](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html).

Inside of EJBs you have to use the [`EJBContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html) (or the [`SessionContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html)).

Comment: Ah I see. I was hoping that the Request Scoped SecurityContext would be able to be mapped into the Stateless EJB. No luck though it seems. Kind of annoying that Glassfish doesn't throw an warnings or errors that the annotations could not be processed and the value injected. Anything special I should have to do to get the EJBContext to inject? I tried it already and it was null as well.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, I have solved using the EJBContext inside the EJBs, as pointed by unwichtich.

In conclusion, SecurityContext is only for the JAX-RS bean, I have used the EJBContext object inplace of SecurityContext into the other java beans.
You can also use the SessionContext object but EJBContext interface resembles the SecurityContext one. Here is an usage example:

```
@DeclareRoles({"administrator","operator","user"})
@PermitAll
@Stateless
public class myFacade {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistencePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource EJBContext securityContext;

    public DataStuff find(Object id) {
        //Now the securityContext is != null :-D
        String username = securityContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
        if(username.equals("gino"){
            return null;
        }
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }
}
```

It works auto-magically as expected, the EJB sees the same Principal(s) as the JAX-RS servlet do.