# JAX-RS + EJB, SecurityContext inside ejb is null, on WildFly 10.1

Tags: java, security, ejb, jax-rs, wildfly

I am developing  for the first time a JavaEE application that (tries to..)employs the ejb security features.
I am working with WildFly 10.1.
I have created a Jdbc security-domain and configured a form-based login. The access to web methods and url paths and the login work right (prevents the access to unauthorized ones and authorizes access after login).

I have a set of beans that implements the (Jax-RS) REST interface and I have a set of ejb Stateless bean that implements the business logic of my application.

These are the snipped of jboss-web.xml and web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>myDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        <role-name>operator</role-name>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config><!-- 3 -->
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/public/login.html</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/public/error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Here follows the examples of the code implementing the REST interface and the java beans, I have deleted bolerplate code and obfuscated my "use case" related names.
Example of one Jax-RS bean:

```
@Stateless
@Path("api/my")
public class myFacadeREST {
    @EJB
    myFacade myFacade;

    @Context  //injected response proxy supporting multiple threads
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void create(DataStuff entity) {
        myFacade.create(entity);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public DataStuff find(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return myFacade.find(id);
    }
}
```

And the snippet of the injected EJB, where I need to programmatically access the security context and principal informations:

```
@DeclareRoles({"administrator","operator","user"})
@PermitAll
@Stateless
public class myFacade {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistencePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Context SecurityContext securityContext;
    @Resource SecurityContext sc; //I have tried both :-(

    public DataStuff find(Object id) {
        //Here I get a NullPointerException, tried both sc and securitycontext
        String username = securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        if(username.equals("gino"){
            return null;
        }
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }
}
```

I have tried with and without @DeclareRoles, @PermitAll, but the securityContext and sc variables are allways null. Perhaps I miss something but I have understood that security infos magically moves throught bean calls.

**Questions**

- How do I propagate the security context from the Jax-RS class to the
  ejb beans?
- Is the security info managed auto-magically as I expected? or..
- Do I need to improve or add other jboss-?.xml configuration files?
  or..
- Have I to change something in the calling Jax-RS beans in order to
  propagate the security informations to the called beans? or..
- Or am doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance
Regards

Comment: That question is the source of the solution below, I added few useful details(lacking in the source), hope useful.

Comment: Just to answer your first two bullet points, the container is responsible for *propagating* the security context, you don't normally need to be concerned with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, the question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132547/context-injection-in-stateless-ejb-used-by-jax-rshttp://)

SecurityContext is only for the JAX-RS bean, you need to inject an EJBContext object inplace of SecurityContext one into the other java beans.
You can also use the SessionContext object but EJBContext interface resembles the SecurityContext one. Here is the working version:

```
@DeclareRoles({"administrator","operator","user"})
@PermitAll
@Stateless
public class myFacade {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistencePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource EJBContext securityContext;

    public DataStuff find(Object id) {
        //Now the securityContext is != null :-D
        String username = securityContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
        if(username.equals("gino"){
            return null;
        }
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }
}
```